# How to call the Rest Api that is present in Solr from Grails?

Tags: grails, solr, grails-2.0

I m trying to fetch the Rest API(i.e Autocomplete/spell check etc) that is present in LWE/solr from the Grails Frame Work,
But I am not getting how to do that,if any one can help me

Thanks in Advance. ..

Answer (score 1):

There is a solr plugin that interface with a solr installation.

http://grails.org/plugin/solr

Comment: Isn't that plugin for indexing the application's data rather than invoking a remote SOLR instance?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to programmatically invoke SOLR is to use the [SOLRJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) API